# Unable to convert arraylist of type string to arralist integer and pass the new list to a method

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public class PGM2 {

    public static void main (String [] args){
        try {
            Scanner scn = new Scanner(new File("/D:filename"));
            scn.useDelimiter("/n");
            ArrayList<String> Stringarraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
            while (scn.hasNext()){
                Stringarraylist.add((scn.next()));
            }
            ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (String s : Stringarraylist){
                numbers.add (Integer.parseInt(s));
            }
            //numbers.add((Stringarraylist.get(i)));
            System.out.println("the given list is :"+ numbers);
            scn.close();`enter code here`
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("the exception found is "+ e);
        }
    }
}
```

My input file has some values I intend to use them later in the program. I have used an `ArrayList` to collect all those values but unable to store them directly into the `ArrayList<Integer>` hence tried to type cast but `NumberNotFound` exception is coming.

Comment: Well that mean your try to parse a String that does not represent a number.

Comment: Typo: The escape sequence for newline is `\n`, not `/n`.

Comment: What are the contents of your file? Also, if you are trying to split by lines, the delimiter `/n` is incorrect, you should be using `\n`. Also the `Scanner` class has a function called 'hasNextInt()` and `nextInt()` methods you should look into.

Comment: Have you tried printing out the Strings without parsing to verify that you're trying to parse the right thing?

Comment: Change your statement for printing the exception to print `e.getMessage()` - it will often provide a more helpful message about what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This will work.

- variable names start from small letter.
- you need to use /r and /n for new lines - it depends is you are using windows or linux.

Here is the working code:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?[0-9]+");

    try {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(new File("C:/workspace/test.txt"));
        scn.useDelimiter("[\\r\\n]+");
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (scn.hasNext()) {
           String s = scn.next().trim();
           if (p.matcher(s).matches()) { // this will skip invalid lines
                numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
            }
        }
        System.out.println("the given list is :" + numbers);
        scn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("the exception found is " + e);
    }
}
```

And second solution, using better Scanner class. Scanner can find integers for you.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
      Scanner scn = new Scanner(new File("C:/workspace/test.txt"));
      ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      while (scn.hasNext()) {
        if(scn.hasNextInt()){
          numbers.add(scn.nextInt());
        }
      }
      System.out.println("the given list is :" + numbers);
      scn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("the exception found is " + e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have removed few lines:) Meaning is the same.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply ..but my input file has some negative integers as well ..will this work fine ?

Comment: for (int k =0; k < Stringarraylist.size();k++){
         int temp = Integer.parseInt(Stringarraylist.get(k));
         
         System.out.println("the input just passed is :"+temp);

Comment: i am getting numbernotfound exception there